# How to get sum of recent N value or available value of each item with respect given cut off date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

To be honest, I am very new in programming and learned some of the panda's basic functionality.
I am able to do group by and sum price of each item, but not able to specifically apply cut of date and do summation.

Below are my input data and expected result. Requesting to help how to achieve this using pandas. [data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcjfb.png)

In the below data, N=5 (no of values need to consider before the cut of date), the expected result for item Grape is 88 i.e. sum of entry 7,6,5,4, and 3. And orange is 90 (entries 13,12,11,10), here only 4 entry available, so considered all.

```
    EntryDate   Itemname    Price   Cut off date    Expected result
1   3/9/2020    Grape   16  3/15/2020                88
2   3/10/2020   Grape   15  3/15/2020                88
3   3/11/2020   Grape   12  3/15/2020                88
4   3/12/2020   Grape   18  3/15/2020                88
5   3/13/2020   Grape   20  3/15/2020                88
6   3/13/2020   Grape   18  3/15/2020                88
7   3/14/2020   Grape   20  3/15/2020                88
8   3/15/2020   Grape   12  3/15/2020                88
9   3/16/2020   Grape   19  3/15/2020                88
10  2/10/2020   Orange  22  2/17/2020                90
11  2/11/2020   Orange  21  2/17/2020                90
12  2/12/2020   Orange  26  2/17/2020                90
13  2/13/2020   Orange  21  2/17/2020                90
14  2/20/2020   Orange  26  2/17/2020                90
```

Comment: Please show a working piece of code you wrote yet about your trial to solve this problem, and give specific error messages or details you would like help about.  No image please, copy paste your code/data properly, so we can copy paste and reproduce, so it is easier to answer your question.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Could you precise your cutoff algo? Keep the most recent 5 values before the given date. What do you do if you have 2 or more entries for the limit date ? use the record order ? or have a bigger N ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert columns to datetimes, then filter rows by `cut off date` by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and aggregate `sum` in lambda function for last `N` values by [`Series.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tail.html), last for new column use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
N = 5
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Cut off date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Cut off date'])

s = (df[df['Date'].lt(df['Cut off date'])]
                  .groupby('Itemname')['Price']
                  .agg(lambda x: x.tail(N).sum()))
df['new'] = df['Itemname'].map(s)
print (df)
    Entry       Date Itemname  Price Cut off date  Expected result  new
0       1 2020-03-09    Grape     16   2020-03-15               88   88
1       2 2020-03-10    Grape     15   2020-03-15               88   88
2       3 2020-03-11    Grape     12   2020-03-15               88   88
3       4 2020-03-12    Grape     18   2020-03-15               88   88
4       5 2020-03-13    Grape     20   2020-03-15               88   88
5       6 2020-03-13    Grape     18   2020-03-15               88   88
6       7 2020-03-14    Grape     20   2020-03-15               88   88
7       8 2020-03-15    Grape     12   2020-03-15               88   88
8       9 2020-03-16    Grape     19   2020-03-15               88   88
9      10 2020-02-10   Orange     22   2020-02-17               90   90
10     11 2020-02-11   Orange     21   2020-02-17               90   90
11     12 2020-02-12   Orange     26   2020-02-17               90   90
12     13 2020-02-13   Orange     21   2020-02-17               90   90
13     14 2020-02-20   Orange     26   2020-02-17               90   90
```